# ie 9 - css - multiple filter:

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have a page with transparent scrollbars (parts of it) using `filter: chroma()` and some tables that are not fully opague using `filter: alpha()`. My problem is that IE8 will display this fine, IE9 will not. IE9 will only display one or the other transparent, but not both like IE8. Does anyone have some info or tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

IE9 drops support for the old `filter` style, in favour of more standard CSS properties.

For example, if you want opacity, use the `opacity` style, as you would in any other browser. Most other effects that were possible with `filter` can also be done in IE9 using standard CSS. The bonus is that it means you are also supporting other browsers too by using the standard code.

There are one or two features that were in `filter` but IE9 doesn't support the equivalent standard, but most things can be done.

If you really need to keep using the rubbish old `filter` style (for example, if you have a poor quality site that uses them in ways that you can't change), it is possible: you would have to tell IE9 to use IE8 compatibility mode. It's not ideal, and you throw away most of the advantages of using IE9 in the first place, but it can be done.